# How to make a scrollable widget between two fixed widgets

Tags: flutter, scroll, flutter-layout

I want to make a scrollable view between two fixed widgets at top-bottom of the screen.
My layout is as follows:

[image: Layout image]

Currently I am having bottom overflowed error as described in the picture below:

[image: Image with overflow error]

What I am aiming for is to have the goto payment button at the bottom fixed and the rest of the view in the module to be scrollable.

[image: Layout image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your `column` inside `Expanded` and `SingleChildScrollView` as following

```
//...
Expanded(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        //...
      ]
    ),
  ),
),
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the column you want to scroll in a singleChildScrollView should resolve your issue:

```
body: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Im not scrollable'),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('I am scrollable'),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```